# How to remove the hypelink from WPF RichTextbox at runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have a WPF `RichTextBox` and using `FlowDocument` I have added a `Paragraph`.  Inside that `Paragraph` I have also added multiple `Hyperlink`s.

I want to remove the hyperlinks at runtime and replace them with some text.
All hyperlinks share the same event handlers, so I think I should write the hyperlink removal code inside the hyperlink click event handler.

How can I remove that particular hyperlinks from the Paragraph which is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's too late, but I found a much simpler way to remove a hyperlink :

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = sender as HyperLink;
// we make a selection from BEFORE the hyperlink to AFTER the hyperlink
rtb.Selection.Select(hyperlink.ElementStart, hyperlink.ElementEnd);
// we replace the hyperlink element by a simple text
rtb.Selection.Text = rtb.Selection.Text;
```

It works pretty well for me.

Comment: pretty nice. Will Hyperlink after replacing still exist?

Comment: hyperlink will not visible after execution of this code , but perhaps it may exist behind the scenes , but not visible.